# Implementation of solution for multithreaded resource sharing problem?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to figure out an implementation for a solution to a problem I outlined in another [Programmers.SE question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/329307/150520). I need to find a solution for this problem in C# most likely using the collection in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace.

My problem is a classic problem related to the [Dining Philosophers Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem). I have a finite set of resources that need to be used by multiple threads. My current implementation of a solution involves a sort of signalling system to let other threads know when they may start using a resource. I have actually created a nice analogy.

---

Resources are seen as amusement park rides that can only fit a single rider at a time. Threads/tasks/units of work are seen as groups of people that wish to ride multiple different rides at the same time.

When a group of people enters the park they stop at the ticketing stand, each purchase a ticket to their respective ride, and each get in line for their respective lines, *all simultaneously*. Each of these groups of people will only start riding a ride once they are all at the front of the line, otherwise they will wait first in line at their respective rides until all of them are first in line.

---

This solution would work but the concurrent collection in C# make it hard to implement properly. (Going along with the analogy) As a result of each person in the group having to purchase tickets and get in line all simultaneously at some point I have to make multiple modifications to some concurrent collection atomically. In C# there is no mechanism to do this in `System.Collections.Concurrent`.

In C# I have the following data structures to represent the analogy above

```
ConcurrentDictionary<IResource, ConcurrentQueue<Guid>> ResourceWaitQueues { get; set; }
ConcurrentDictionary<ITask, ConcurrentDictionary<IResource, Guid>> TasksToDo { get; set; }
```

**[Step 1.a]** When a new `ITask` is generated it is interrogated for the `IResource`s that it requires to be ran. For each `IResource` it needs a new `Guid` is generated. A `KeyValuePair` is created for this `ITask` and inserted into `TasksToDo`.

**[Step 1.b]** The `Guid` created for each `IResource` the `ITask` needed is then inserted into the corresponding `ConcurrentQueue<Guid>` in the `ResourcesWaitQueues` object.

**[DispatchThread]** The dispatch thread (TPL `Task`) is started. This thread continually loops over the `TasksToDo` structure and checks to see if the current `ITask`'s `List<Guid>` needed to run are at the front of the `ConcurrentQueue`s in the `ResourceWaitQueues`. If so it is started, otherwise it is skipped.

**[TaskRunningThread]** When a `ITask` is found to be ready to run it is ran. Once complete the `List<Guid>` it hold are dequeued from their respective `ConcurrentQueue` in `ResourceWaitQueues`.

---

As you should notice the issue with this solution is that I must make multiple adds or removes to `ConcurrentQueue` and `ConcurrentDictionary` when a new `ITask` is generated or when an `ITask` has completed. If the DispatchThread or TaskRunningThread manages to interleave with each other then it is possible that `Guid` are never added or removed from their respective collections.

I'd like to think I am experienced enough to write my own concurrent collection to allow multiple atomic modifications, though I would much rather use out of the box, well developed classes.

---

So my question is, **is there a way to solve this problem with the out of the box `System.Collections.Concurrent` collections?**

Answer (score 1):

You probably need some kind of locking when simultaneously accessing multiple queues.  If you really want to stick to System.Collections.Concurrent, you can store a single token in any [IProducerConsumerCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287147(v=vs.110).aspx).  But it would be kind of silly.

I have combined concurrent collections and used [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx).  When performing a single operation on a single queue such as [`GetorAdd()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(v=vs.110).aspx), I would use [`EnterReadLock()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.enterreadlock(v=vs.110).aspx) relying on the collection's own thread safety and allowing other simple operations simultaneously.  When performing a 'transaction' of operations on one or more collection's, I would use [`EnterWriteLock()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.enterwritelock(v=vs.110).aspx) signalling exclusive use of all concurrent collections.